# How to number the lines according to a field with awk?

Tags: awk

I wonder whether there is a way using awk to number the lines according to a field. For example,

Input

```
2334 332
2334 546
2334 675
7890 222
7890 134
234  45
.
.
.
```

Based on the 1st field, I would have the following output

Output

```
1 2334 332
1 2334 546
1 2334 675
2 7890 222
2 7890 134
3 234  45
.
.
.
```

I would be grateful for your help.

Cheers,

T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's how,

```
awk '!a[$1]++{c++}{print c, $0}' file
1 2334 332
1 2334 546
1 2334 675
2 7890 222
2 7890 134
3 234  45
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk 'last != $1 { line = line + 1 } { last = $1; print line, $0 }'`